# Database user does not exists

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, sqlalchemy

I'm creating an app in Flask, with Postgres SQL as a database. My database root user has the username "user", password "password" and a database "rainbow_database". I've followed [these instructions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html) to create a URL string which ended up as the following:

```
postgresql://user:password@db:5432/rainbow_database
```

I use the create_engine function from SQL alchemy to create my engine, but when I do so, I get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  database "user" does not exist
```

Looks to me like the function is taking my username as the database name, any idea what could be causing it?

**Edit 1**: Here is the code I used to make the connection, the URI is actually in an environment variable called 'DB_URI'

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.exc import DatabaseError
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base, declared_attr
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy_utils import database_exists, create_database, drop_database


engine = create_engine(os.getenv('DB_URI'), convert_unicode=True)
```

I'm using the [Flusk](https://github.com/dimmg/flusk) app as a boilerplate

**Edit 2**: Everything is running on docker, these are my files:

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  api:
    build: ./core
    env_file: ./core/core.env
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src

  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    env_file: ./database/database.env
    volumes:
      - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

volumes:
  database-data:
```

core.env:

```
FLASK_ENV=development
SECRET_KEY=secret
DB_URI=postgresql://user:password@db:5432/rainbow_database
```

database.env:

```
POSTGRES_USER=user
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
POSTGRES_DB=rainbow_database
```

**Edit 3**: I changed the files as a troubleshooting step, they now look like this:

database.env:

```
POSTGRES_USER=username
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
POSTGRES_DB=user
```

core.env:

```
FLASK_ENV=development
SECRET_KEY=secret
DB_URI=postgresql://username:password@db:5432/user
```

And now I get the error message:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  database "username" does not exist
```

Seems to me that sqlalchemy is taking the URL string and interpreting that the username is actually the table name, but I'm not finding the mistake in it.

Comment: You will need to show the actual code you used to make the connection to get anything approaching  a useful answer.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver just added it

Comment: The error indicates a bad database URL.

Comment: @KlausD. Yes, the URL above is exactly the one I'm using but I'm not noticing anything wrong with it

Comment: @Danizavtz it's all in a docker container built from Postgres image, I've set up the user and password as environment variables also, and I am able to access the DB using DBeaver with these credentials

Comment: @Danizavtz that is incorrect. If the user did not have `LOGIN` you would get: `role "user" is not permitted to log in`. The error is saying what the problem is, that the role does not exist.

Comment: I was just double checking I have a project with postgres url, and in this project I use the connection string like that: `"postgres://postgres:postgres@0.0.0.0/postgres"` I do not used `postgresql`. But it is a nodejs project.

Comment: I'm guessing you are not connecting to the database you think you are. Check the logs of the Postgres server(s) and look for connections and errors.

Comment: That's it, as you use docker container, you have to expose correct ports. If using docker-compose you should not point to localhost as address.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver this shows up as soon as I start the machine db_1   | 2021-01-27 15:11:45.010 UTC [33] FATAL:  database "user" does not exist

Comment: @Danizavtz I'm not really using localhost, I did use my db name, I changed it because I didn't want to expose all the volumes here on the internet. I'll edit to remove the folder names, and edit my question to show the docker-compose

Comment: @Danizavtz just added the actual code with information on the docker container

Comment: It looks like you haven’t added the user to `pg_hba.conf`.

Comment: @rfkortekaas I entered the machine looks like there's already a pg_hba.conf there, I did not configure it, could his be the problem?

Comment: Yes, otherwise you cannot login with password authentication.

Comment: @rfkortekaas the weird thing is I was able to log in from outside the docker container using dbever

Comment: Does `db` resolve in the `api` container? Maybe you need to use db.docker-internal or something like that.

Comment: @rfkortekaas looks like it can, it's not given an error of the database not found but rather that the table does not exist, I've updated with more info that might help

Comment: What happens if you omit the environment variable and use the complete connection string directly in `create_engine`.

Comment: It gives the same error